Navigation2 gracefully stop robot when there is obstacle ahead
I am currently tuning my MPPI controller, everything is working quite well.
However, I have a question on 1 scenario where my robot is about to pass a narrow doorway, if there is a person at the doorway, my robot will stop there(there is only 1 path that could make through the doorway) and wait until the person move away. The thing is that when the robot see the person, it stop aggressively making stuff on the robot fall off because of inertia by the previous velocity.
By checking the /cmd_vel_nav, I can see that controller_server and behavior_server could publish a zero velocity to the robot base. So in above case, which one publishes zero velocity ? Is there any approach that help gracefully stopping the robot like slowing it down a bit then stop completely and go to wait stage.
I have try my self with velocity smoother, but seem like it does not work in this case. Below is my config for velocity smoother:
velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.7, 0.0, 2.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.7, 0.0, -2.0]
    max_accel: [1.4, 0.0, 2.0]
    max_decel: [-1.4, 0.0, -2.0]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

Below is my velocity record:

Update: Seems like it is the function publishZeroVelocity() in controller_server.cpp is publishing this zero velocity when a cancel controller request is called. Is it possible if we create a function that publishing cmd_vel value that decreases overtime before publishing zero velocity ?
